# Where Can i find the lecture Videos of BSD 2011

Tags: nt.number-theory, ag.algebraic-geometry, analytic-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

i recently heard that there was a conference on Birch and Swinnerton dyer conjecture Held at Cambridge on May 4 until May 6,
the main theme is  "The conference marks the 50th anniversary of the Birch-Swinnerton-Dyer Conjecture and aims both to explain the state of our knowledge and to reflect on the modern approaches to the conjecture and related problems."

but unfortunately i cant find any video archives about the conference in any of the google searches ,but i found some pdf files,and photos which are not informative in the conference site of MR.Tim Dokchitser,

so can anyone give a reference to the video archive site of that conference ,or does the video archive exists???

i forward this question to Mr.William Stein,and Tim dokchitser,who were the key persons in organizing ,if they are successful in giving me the appropriate links of video archive i would be much thankful

thanks a lot everyone,touch your feet for your help

Comment: Dear trust god, I have to confess that the expression "touch your feet for your help" makes me feel quite unconfortable. We are all equal here, despite our different baggage of knowledge and academic rank. I guess that a simple "thanks a lot to everyone, any help will be appreciated" would be enough :-) 

Comment: @Francesco Polizzi:but i am so curious to learn advanced things ,but no one in this world  helps me,everyone tries to suppress me,so thats only the way ,i am begging

Comment: @Trust God: begging does not help. Working hard is the only way. No one wants to suppress you, but you should follow the advise that many people have given to you in these days: read books and do exercises, in order to reach a "basic mathematical knowledge". Then you can start asking difficult questions. After all you are young, you have time. We all did so. 

Comment: @francesco polizzi:thanks a lot,you were like cloud with silver lining,but i have read the basic mathematics,and i am very far that we dont have sophisticated things,and i am not a mathematician,i am learning mathematics privately,and i understand them,i know basic things pretty well,thats why i understood them,imagine how can a person without having knowledge in basic things,dare to ask something about advanced things,without knowing, what these modular forms,elliptic curves,hodge and tate theories are??

Comment: I was there and went to all the lectures.  I didn't notice anyone videotaping them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems that the lectures were not recorded (there are only photos on the conference website); 
so there is no point in searching for the videos.

However, there are a few video excerpts available from Professor Stein's channel..small consolation.

(1) [bsd1](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vo9yWAhBxAs)

(2) [bsd2](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IIN2__t5Bsk)

(3) [bsd3](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YcMgwfsP0u0)

Comment: but very small duration,i hoped for more,as i can never go there

Answer (score 6):

There was an École d'été sur la conjecture de Birch et Swinnerton-Dyer in Paris in the summer of 2002.  The [videos](http://bsd-2002.institut.math.jussieu.fr/videos/) of the lectures (by P. Colmez, H. Darmon, B. Edixhoven, B. Mazur, J. Nekovár, J. Oesterlé, W. Stein, E. Urban and S. Zhang)
are available.

Comment: @chandan singh dalawat: a lot chandan,touch your legs for your help,its really helped me

Comment: No need to touch anybody's feet.  You should realise
that people are more than willing to help (and might 
feel queasy about their feet being touched).  You 
should also realise that Mathoverflow is for precise
questions pertaining to mathematics at the research 
level.  You seem to have a burning desire to talk 
about number theory at that level, but you don't seem 
to have the requisite background.  For your own good,
try to acquire that background first.

Comment: The link is now http://bsd-2002.institut.math.jussieu.fr/videos/

Answer (score 2):

I checked that the BSD conference was held at DPMMS, not the Isaac Newton Institute (INI). Quite a lot of video lectures are kept online at the INI website, and there is much to be learned there on many subjects. Similarly, the Mathematical Sciences Research Institute at Berkeley (MSRI) has many video lectures available on line. Probably other mathematical institutes around the world do this,
and the number doing so is likely to increase. So there are many opportunities available online to learn from high calibre mathematicians for those with a desire to do so. In some case, instructional  conferences outlining the basic underlying theory are available too, prior to the research level conferences. Nevertheless, following such lectures usually would require a mathematician at an early stage to have previously undertaken much independent study and hard work.

Comment: Is this really an answer?

Anyway this seems like the first of trust god's questions which is legitimate (although asked in a profoundly confusing way) and is just a reference request.

Comment: I did write out a pretty constructive answer, and then thought better of it, so I deleted what I said, not meaning any disrespect
to the question or the person who asked it. Since I am not a registered user, (though I have unsuccessfully tried to become one), I could not remove my own comments completely, but had to leave at least 15 characters

Comment: @ Richard: I managed to figure out how to reinstate my earlier text,
so I have now done that.